# ImageButton Stretching Background Image

Tags: android, scale, padding, imagebutton, stretch

I am trying to create an ImageButton with no border but I am running into an issue with the sizing of the image button.

Using Eclipse ADT I drag an ImageButton to the layout and select my background image. The image button appears as follows:

[image: initial image button]

As you can see there is a border between the background image and the image button perimeter which I would like to get rid of. To do so, I set the padding property to 0dp. The image button now looks like this:

[image: image button after setting padding to 0dp]

Finally, I set the scale type to fitXY:

[image: image button after setting scale type]

Notice that the image is *stretched* and is no longer the size of the original image. (I want the ImageButton size to be exactly the same size as the background image.)

Here is a snapshot of all 3 images next to each other to make the difference more clear:

[image: all image buttons]

I have tried re-sizing the image, setting the max size properties, etc. but nothing seems to prevent the image button from stretching the background image.

How do I prevent the image from *stretching* like it is?

*UPDATE*

I also tried setting scale type to matrix but here is what happened:

[image: image button with scale type matrix]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your image as `android:background` for button and set `layout_height` and `layout_width` for button to `wrap_content`

Comment: It is already set to wrap_content. I guess that's the default when you drag an image button using Eclipse ADT.

Comment: Also, in your case you don't need an ImageButton. You can use simple Button without text

Comment: The problem I have found with doing that is if I set the background of a simple button to an image I no longer get the *click* effect in the UI.

Comment: in this case you need to write selector for pressed state and normal state.
Look at http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Comment: I am going to go with your solution because I have decided to use a button with a selector. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help, but I also know its best practice to make different sized images from android development.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ImageView` instead and set it to be `clickable`. Set the `scaleType` to `matrix` (which will cause the ImageView to be as big as the image inside of it).

The problem with `ImageButton` is that it adds a background that causes padding, etc.

Comment: I will try that now thanks! Is that generally what people do when trying to make custom buttons?

Comment: Yes. You can also override the ImageButton's background yourself. Make it a transparent color, for example.

Comment: I just tried using ImageView but the issue I have now is I dont get that nice *click* (blinking) effect when I click it. I like the click effect because it gives the user feedback that they have pressed a button.

Comment: If you want that 'blinking' effect, you'll be back to ImageButton and will have some padding around your image. Just try to set the 'scaleType="matrix"' on your ImageButton and see what happens.

Comment: matrix did something even stranger :) check my original post for a pic

Comment: Yeah, not that surprising :). You need to write your own (selector/state-list) background for that to get the effect you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can set 
android:background="@null"